# How to run ansible playbook with Bamboo or jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, ansible, bamboo

I want to execute an ansible playbook using Bamboo or jenkins. However, the build failed because I can't pass the ssh password .
Have you any idea please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run an ansible playbook from bamboo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553849/how-to-run-an-ansible-playbook-from-bamboo)

Comment: You [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553849/how-to-run-an-ansible-playbook-from-bamboo) this same question yesterday, then neglected to follow up with any of the clarifying questions.  We know just as little about your situation now as we did then; answering the question would be significantly more helpful than reposting.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [key authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) 
and private_key_file option in [ansible config file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#private-key-file)

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins you can use [SSH Agent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin) to serve the credentials to Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your ansewers , i used a simple solution :

from Bamboo or jenkins i used the sshpass package to execute my playbook .

```
sshpass -p 'mypassword' ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml --ask-pass -c paramiko -vvvv
```